# How do I disable the vertical indent lines that show which begin goes with which end in Delphi Community Edition?

Tags: delphi

Exactly what the question asks. Is there maybe a setting which I can use to turn it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can find the setting at

**Tools** -> **Options...** -> **User Interface** -> **Editor** -> **Color** -> **Structural Highlighting** -> **Enable Structural Highlighting**.

Simply uncheck this checkbox.